# Empty Message from SQS with HHVM and Laravel

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel-4, amazon-sqs, hhvm

I am running Laravel on HHVM and working with Amazon SQS. I am able to connect to the Queue and push messages to it. I am able to connect and receive from it, as well.

**The Problem:**
With HHVM the jobs returned from the Queue are empty, whereas when I run the site on traditional php 5.5, i get the full queue message

Response with HHVM

```
Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model Object
(
    [structure:protected] => 
    [data:protected] => Array
    (
    )

)
```

Response using PHP 5.5.9

```
object(Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model)#1154 (2) {
  ["structure":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["data":protected]=>
  array(2) {
    ["ResponseMetadata"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["RequestId"]=>
      string(36) "requestID here"
    }
    ["Messages"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["Body"]=>
        string(102) "{"job":"GameWisp\\Commands\\ProcessThisThing","data":{"url":"https:\/\/domain.com\/thing\/id"}}"
        ["MD5OfBody"]=>
        string(32) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"    
        ["ReceiptHandle"]=>
        string(300) "stuff was here"
        ["MessageId"]=>
        string(36) "ID was here"
        ["Attributes"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["ApproximateReceiveCount"]=>
          string(1) "3"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Details:**

- I am using the aws sdk and loading it via composer.
- It seems to me that the problem is actually happening somewhere in the aws sdk

Have any of you run into anything like this before?

Comment: are you still seeing this issue or did it get resolved? i'm contemplating having another java component or to try and see if this work directly via php + hhvm with aws sdk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS SDK for PHP is not guaranteed to work on HHVM. HHVM still has some issues to fix before Guzzle and the AWS SDK for PHP will be fully compatible.

Comment: One particular Guzzle / HHVM related bug if anyone wants a secondary source to refer to:

https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/1961

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have done some further research on this, and it seems there is a Guzzle issue on HHVM here: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/1961 that seems to be one of the issues we hit in our problem.

Additionally, I have brought this up with the HHVM folks and I believe they are going to be adding it to their http://hhvm.com/frameworks page, so at least it gets more visibility.

Do you think you guys will be helping fix any of these issues, or will you be relying on the HHVM team?

Comment: Mostly relying on the HHVM team. We don't have the resources to focus on that at the moment. We may decide to prioritize it later though if we get enough requests.